# How to store this array in to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want store this array in to string,so I used toString method() but its display objects in the console log**

I create multiple input filed and i want get this multiple values into the string (separate by commars (,) and store to the database)

```
  import { useState } from "react";
    function AddRemoveInputField() {
      const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
        {
          fullName: "",
        },
      ]);
    
      const addInputField = () => {
        setInputFields([
          ...inputFields,
          {
            fullName: "",
          },
        ]);
      };
      const removeInputFields = (index) => {
        const rows = [...inputFields];
        rows.splice(index, 1);
        setInputFields(rows);
      };
      const handleChange = (index, evnt) => {
        const { name, value } = evnt.target;
        const list = [...inputFields];
        list[index][name] = value;
        setInputFields(list);    
        
      };      
   
    
    console.log(inputFields)    
     
    }
```

**Image is attached bellow**

[image]

Comment: You're not calling `toString` anywhere.

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(inputFields)`.

Comment: using JSON.stringify(inputFields) its returens like this [{"fullName":"ff"},{"fullName":"ff"},{"fullName":"hhhh"}]   but I want store it into the  fullName :"ff","gg","ghk" like this.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I create multiple input filed and get full names and store it to the array , but I want save this array in to database. so in the daatabase have one filed like full name to store that multiple filename array. so that I want to send this array as a string .

Comment: You can use the map function of an array to iterate over the inputFields.
``` inputFields.map(field=>field.fullName)```
That would map all objects within your array into the value of the key fullName

Comment: so sth like this? `array.map(obj => '"' + obj.fullName + '"').join(',')`